# ee.Feature extraction from ee.FeatureCollection by Feature index

Tags: google-earth-engine, feature-collection

I have a tabular asset in Google Earth Engine that has two features. To extract them one by one in a for-loop I had to introduce site_id property (column) and filter based on that value:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) { 
  var feature = myAsset.filterMetadata('site_id', 'equals', i).first();
};
```

How can one extract one `ee.Feature` directly using the Feature Index which is present in the asset?

I am looking for an analogy of `ee.FeatureCollection.first()` but `.second()`, `.third()` etc
[image]

Comment: use `.toList()` and then `.get()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your table contains *only two features*, using a list is a good way to extract the individual features, and quite efficient.

```
var myAssetList = myAsset.toList(10);  // number must be at least 2 but can be a generous allowance
... use myAssetList.get(0) and myAssetList.get(1) ...
```

However, the *order* of features from assets is **not guaranteed to be the same** as the order in the table you uploaded (instead, it's based on a spatial index). Therefore, *if* you intend to do something different with the two features, **and you want your results to be reproducible,** it is actually a better idea to keep doing what you already have, with IDs you assigned yourself (`site_id`), because that way if you upload a new version of the table with changed points, the numbering of the features will still be predictable.